# Change the icons of dataList

Tags: css, jsf, icons, primefaces-mobile

I'm using a `<p:dataList>` to display vehicles. Everything is okay except the icons. My icons look like that right now

[image]

and i want them to look like that

[image].

I know how to modify the datalist itself using css, but not the buttons in the list. So how can i replace the icons using css?

If I do this, i can color it yellow and place an image, but not replacing it:

```
.ui-paginator-next {
background-color: yellow !important;
background-image: url(#{resource['images/logo.png']});
```

}

Comment: Look very carefully (with a browser developer tool) where the icon is set... (hint: it is one level deeper)

Comment: i found now the tag `.ui-icon-carat-r:after`, and can replace it with an image of my own. thx. but how can I replace it with another ui-icon or fa-icon?